# string em C retornando simbolos ao invés de caracteres

Tags: c, visual-studio

Tenho este código simples em linguagem C que recebe um valor de entrada e retorna o valor na tela. Porem ao invés de mostrar a string na tela, ele mostra simbolos comom se fossem barras. Quando faço o procedimento com números inteiros, ele mostra o valor corretamente, o erro só ocorre quando faço com strings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char nome[61];

    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf_s("%s", nome);

    printf("O nome armazenado foi: %s", nome);

    //getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: scanf_s? use apenas scanf

Comment: Aqui gera exceção de violação de acesso ao gravar.

Comment: quando uso scanf ele mostra um erro. `Erro C4996: 'scanf': esta função ou variável pode não ser segura. Considere usar scanf_s em vez disso. Para desativar a suspensão de uso, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. Consulte a ajuda online para obter detalhes.` Inseri  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS antes dos includes e funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: O `scanf_s` é uma variante da Microsoft para especificar quantidade de input lido e evitar *buffer overflow attack*. Isso significa que a sua leitura está errada pois falta o tamanho na leitura.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Use a função gets().

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
char nome[61];

```
printf("Digite seu nome: ");
gets(nome);

printf("O nome armazenado foi: %s", nome);

return 0;
```

}